# Ng-change on div index change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexing, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get an ng-change function to be called every time the $index of the object changes. The object(s) are a list of draggable div's that you can reorder on the screen.

The index is the location of the object, and every time it changes I need to update the api, this isn't the part I'm having trouble with.

It's getting the ng-change to actually call the function when the $index value changes. Any advice?

```
<div class="col s7 offset-s1 tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Drag cards to move their position.">
  <form id="dashDragForm">
    <div class="card-panel hoverable center-align"
         **ng-model="$index" ng-change="positionUpdate(current, $index)"** 
         ng-class="{'draggable-md': dashboard.Panels.length < 5 ,'draggable-sm': dashboard.Panels.length > 4}" 
         ng-repeat="current in dashboard.Panels">
        <div class="row col-s12">
            <i ng-if="current.Type == 'Table'" class="material-icons left white-text">line_style</i>
            <i ng-if="current.Type == 'Chart'" class="material-icons left white-text">timeline</i>
            <i class="close material-icons right modal-trigger" data-target="removePanelModal" ng-click="openDeleteModal(current, $index)">close</i>
        </div>
            <h6 class="white-text">{{current.Title}}</h4>
        <div class="row col-s12">
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle ? or provide full code ?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure where is a problem from this desc

Comment: a jsfiddle won't really help. I need the ng-change function to be called when the index changes, and that isn't happening..

Comment: How the index is changing ? by any event ? or you want to call ng-change in ng-repeat loop ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the documentation says ng-change should be called every time the model changes of that object, and that isn't happening, thats the problem. :) The index is changed every time someone moves the object on the screen, as the ng-repeated objects are draggable

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly states that the `ng-change` directive only evaluates the expression when the *user* changes the *input*. Users enter inputs on `input`, `select`, or `textarea` tags. In this case the `ng-model` directive is not on an `input`, `select`, or `textarea` tag. It is on a `div` tag.

From the Docs:

> ### ngChange
>
> Evaluate the given expression **when the** *user* **changes the input**. The expression is evaluated immediately, unlike the JavaScript onchange event which only triggers at the end of a change (usually, when the user leaves the form element or presses the return key).
>
> The `ngChange` expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> **It will not be evaluated:**
>
> - **if the model is changed programmatically** and not by a change to the input value

-- [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

If you want an expression to be evaluated on progammatic changes, use [`scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)